RDP with having to create a AD
I'm trying to connect to a Windows Server 2022 cloud-hosted machine using a remote desktop connection.
How do I force rdp to connect without any domain name? Or without having to create an Active Directory?
We are running GCWP throughout the whole company and have a Google Workspace.
Hope to read some great solutions

Open your Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc).
In the addressbar, type in the hostname and port as you would do normally.
Append /admin to the address.
For example, if your server is located at myrdpserver.com:12389 you would type: myrdpserver.com:12389 /admin
This will connect you to the console as if you are a local user. Supply the login credentials as follows (in this example, the username is Administrator):
Username: .\Administrator
Password: ************
And login.
Do note, without a terminal server role and license, you are limited to having 2 concurrent connections before you have to log out someone, if you have more than one users. If you only have one user, you simply take over eachother's session.

Thank you for the assistance will try it. We have 30 RDP licenses

If you have 30 CAL licenses for RDP usage, you should definitely install the Terminal Server role, after which the above will no longer be necessary.
